# how to filter a database table row and update a specific column in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have a database table and i want to filter it by id and update a specific object (column) with an if condition that i have write.
but it get an error:
attributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

```py
models.py

class Forcast(models.Model):                                                        
    current_complete = models.FloatField(null=True)                                                                    
    optimestic = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    probable = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    pessimistic = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    optimestic_percentage = models.FloatField(null=True)
    probable_percentage = models.FloatField(null=True)
    pessimistic_percentage = models.FloatField(null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=True)




views.py

 def update(request, id):
    item = Forcast.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CharacterNoteForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_complete = Forcast.objects.values('current_complete').get(id=id)
            print(current_complete['current_complete'])
            weight = Forcast.objects.values('weight').get(id=id)
            print(weight)
            optimestic = form.cleaned_data['optimestic']
            probable = form.cleaned_data['probable']
            pessimistic = form.cleaned_data['pessimistic']
            if current_complete['current_complete'] == 65.0 and optimestic:
                optimestic_percentagex = current_complete['current_complete'] * weight['weight']
                if probable or pessimistic:
                    probable_percentagey = current_complete['current_complete'] * weight['weight']
                    pessimistic_percentagez = current_complete['current_complete'] * weight['weight']
                obj = Forcast.objects.filter(id=id).update(optimestic_percentage=optimestic_percentagex)
```

i except that i can update optimestic_percentage with the if condition that i have created.
for more information i am using postgresql

Comment: You don't need `.save()` at the end of your queryset and neither after it. `.update()` will call `.save()` internally. What's happening when you run that?

Comment: i removed .save() but my database didn't update , optimestic_percentage is still null

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` please?

Comment: Please, edit your question with your model class there.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: what is `id` in your views? Maybe try to print that on your code and see what's coming in that? Your code looks right I guess

Comment: i will update view in question for you to understand id better its for filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine but django framework developed in python it means you can use Pythonic way to find solution for your problems so you can use psycopg2 library to connect your database and update your data

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conncetion = psycopg2.connect(user='db_user',
                                  password='***',
                                  host='192.168.0.0',
                                  port='5432',
                                  database='****')
    cursor = conncetion.cursor()

    query_update = ''' UPDATE forecast_Table SET optimestic_percentage = ''' +   optimestic_percentagex + ''' WHERE id= ''' + id + ''' '''
    cursor.execute(query_update)
    conncetion.commit()
    count = cursor.rowcount
    print(count, "Record inserted successfully into forecast table")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Failed to insert record into forecast table", error)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use native sql query in django to update your database